# How to move topmenu inside header wrapper in magento2?

Tags: magento2

How to move topmenu inside header wrapper reference
[magentoroot]vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

I want to move **catalog.topnav** inside **header-wrapper**

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600"/>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
</referenceContainer>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add Following code in [magentoroot]vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to make changes in <magentoRoot>/vendor.  Doing so makes taking updates more difficult because you run the risk of your changes being overwritten by the update.  It's better to extend/override the default.xml in app/design/<yourVendor>/<yourTheme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml.

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work, I had to move the whole `navigation.sections` block. Otherwise the menu would look broken with mobile resolutions. I'm working with Magento 2.1.1 and my theme inherits from `blank`.

In `/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` add this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you create a structure in your
app/design/frontend/yourVendor/yourTheme/Magento_Theme/page_layout

Inside create your default.xml and paste this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>
    </body>
</page>
```